# why wont my aws batch job all start and run in paralllel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

hope someone can help me stop tearing my hair out!

I have a a job with array of ~700 indexes

When i submit the job , I get no more than 20-30 running simultaneously
They all run eventually which leads me to assume its a constraint else where and as all jobs the same, its not permissions/roles/connectivity.

They are array / index jobs, and one job in the queue I can't find any limits on these types of jobs running?

note i'm using ec2 unmanaged as the job was too big for fargate

i've tried

1. double checked they are parallel not sequential
2. dropped individual cpu / membory for each job to 0.25vcpu and 1gb memmory
3. created 'huge' compute environments of max 4096 vpu - no desired or min
4. added upto  3 compute env to a queue (as per limit)

what am i missing? hope someone can point me in a different direction
thanks
Ben

Comment: Can you clarify how you can run 700 jobs on EC2 instances? You span up 700 instances?

Comment: given the compute environment has 4096 vcpu I "assumed' that it brings up the required resources (e.g. multiple ec2 instances) to execute as required - this could be the major mis-understanding I have? not sure why you are allowed to specify compute environment size  with 'unmanaged' compute (it suggests it then finds the resources required to deliver the required compute capacity)

Comment: What about your account limits? Depending on your instance types, the account limit for vCPU usage is much lower then 4096.

Comment: ah ha! you're right you have a 20 ec2 limit per account. - I will ask to increase - THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **EC2 service limits**. AWS Bash will use EC2 to run the jobs, and it will not launch more resources then those specified by the EC2 limits. You can request [increase the service quota of my Amazon EC2 resources](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-limit/) to overcome the issue.